# Creating a new "command" in PHP

Tags: php, frameworks

I've seen some PHP applications use lines of code that are like this:

```
throw new Exception(....);
```

How do I make one of those?  I want to make  sort of 'throw' command.  What is that called?

For example, I'm writing an application, and I want to make the backend easy to use, so I want to use this when a developer wants to set an environment variable:

```
add environment("varname","value");
```

But I have no idea how to make one of those.

Comment: throw is a php keyword. Its part of the Exception handling in PHP. You can't add your own keyword. Read more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Aw, really?  Well thank you anyways :)

Comment: you could just have a function `add_environment` declared as part of you framework initialisation process...

Comment: it is far easier to just set `$_ENV['varname'] = 'value'` Most php programmers will know how to do that. When designing a system or api, you want it to be as standard as possible. don't add stuff because it seems easier to you, or saves a few keystrokes. This will just confuse your users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`throw` is [built into the language](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). Doing what you want would require either modifying the PHP compiler or implementing a [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), neither of which are simple tasks.

Answer (score 3):

[`throw` is a keyword defined by PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). There is no way, without modifying the PHP parser, to do what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better just to use some sort of an object to do what you want. Like this:

```
<?php

class Environment
{
    public $arr = array();
    public function add($name, $value) {
        array_push($this->arr, array($name, $value));
    }
}

$env = new Environment;
$env->add('foo','bar');
print_r($env->arr);
```