# What is a language construct? How (theoreticaly) it is being implemented in C?

Tags: php, c, theory, language-construct, language-concepts

I am familiar with how PHP functions are mapped to functions in C in the C code beneath PHP.
I know in C what a function means and what a MACRO() means.
I do not understand what is a language construct, like `echo`, in PHP means.

Comment: I think it is basically a fancy name for an operator.

Comment: but, operator **is** a function, just different syntax.

Comment: @Itay Moav: php devs just called some group of tokens "language construct". Just accept it.

Comment: @zerkms - ok, so what is a TOKEN? How do I implement one myself? I have not seen anything about this in any tutorial I could find. I want to implement the token `foo` that will send a request to the address I give it as parameter.

Comment: @Itay Moav: token is a term of parser/compiler. It is an "atom" of [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). I think you need to dive into parsers, compilers and php internals to be able to add some `foo`. And I'm sure it is not possible to describe all of this by anyone in an answer.

Comment: And if you were to do that, portability goes out the window.  Just write a function foo() .

Comment: The word "theory" seems completely out of place here. PHP and C are practically-existing languages.

Comment: @BoltClock - why? I need to understand what the term Token/language construct means. @zerkms just explained it in his last comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Language constructs" are operations that are supported by special features in the language. In PHP, mostly anything that isn't a variable or a function is a language construct, as referred on the [list of keywords](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) page.

As a PHP user, you have no way of implementing new language constructs. Those exist only at the language parser level. It seems [your objectives are similar to those of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629481/advanced-php-question/), and the answer will be the same.